# Inherit after String object in JS

Tags: javascript, inheritance, prototype

i want an MyString object which would act like a String object in JS.

```
var test = new MyString("Hello");
"This is test" + test  // should return String object
```

Any ideas making this using JS prototypes?

Comment: Could you please elaborate your question

Comment: Why do you want this? Why don't you just use a normal string?

Comment: `.toString` is your friend.

Comment: `"This is test" + test  ` already return a string , could you elaborate more about what you want

Comment: i want an object which is not of type String, but acts like a string. this is further for tricking an external code

Comment: .toString is fair enough for me :-) ! Thank You.